# Is Unit Test required for Xcode Bots Continuous Integration?

Tags: unit-testing, continuous-integration, bots

I don't have Unit Test script yet. I just want to see that the the integration itself is working and show 'Passed' results, is it possible without set of unit test? Currently, I always get Failed status on Summary of Results.

Comment: Select the "logs" tab near the "summary of results" tab and let us know what the error is. Niels below has the most likely reason

Answer (score 1):

When creating the bot you can uncheck "Perform Test Action" and the bot will not run any unit tests. If you already created the bot you can go the bot under Log Navigator, select it and choose Edit Bot. You will be able to do the same thing there.

Answer (score 0):

Although you haven't created unit tests yourself they are probably already in the project.

If you created your test project from one of the project templates, unit tests are included by default.

The unit tests included by default have a single test that always fails. Locate the unit test and comment out the XCTFail line in the [your project name]Tests.m file

```
//XCTFail(@"No implementation for \"%s\"", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
```